# Managing Magento Footer Content

Tags: magento

I have a portion of page in `footer.phtml` whose content I want to change on each new page,  according to different categories. How can I get this done, or can I access product attribute outside of the product page? Is this possible?

regards

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by defining your own block, though the specifics depend on more detail about the requirement. Define a block that will output the footer content you want whenever you are on a page with the current category defined:

```
$category = Mage::registry("current_category");
if($category) {
    // write your output here
}

$product = Mage::registry("current_product");
if($product) {
    // write your output here
}
```

Note that it is generally bad practice to have your global footer change based on each page. At that point, it isn't a global footer any longer.

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: thanks for the reply sir,well plz have a look at this link http://www.testwsi.com/magento/                                        the pages contains three different Headline section in the footer,which I want to change on Each Category Page In other words wanna show 3 other Category descriptions

Comment: Okay, edit your question to add what you've tried in the footer, preferably taking into account the above ways of getting the current category and product.